# DataTables data column error when adding one more column

Tags: jquery, json, html, datatables

I have a datatable which consumes JSON data. It works perfectly, but now I add 1 more column and I get this error...
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

My code is...

```
<table id="tbl-restitucion" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="bg-info">Fecha</th>
            <th class="bg-info">Hora</th>
            <th class="bg-info">Valor</th>
            <th class="bg-info">Caudal</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <td data-field="fecha_nueva" data-sortable="true" >Fecha</td>
          <td data-field="hora_nueva" data-sortable="true">Hora</td>
          <td data-field="valor" data-sortable="true" class="align-right">Dato</td>
          <td data-field="caudal" data-sortable="true" class="align-right">Caudal</td>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I don't know how to fix this, can you help me?

Comment: You lack `<tr>`'s ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, that's not the error. If fix all <tr> and still have the same error.

Comment: nevertheless, malformed markup *is* an error.  Try to see if you can reproduce the error in this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/976/

Comment: could you please add the DataTable initialization code too